# Please how I fetch user account balance, withdrawals, Loans and Transactions to display in the dashboard?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**My controller code:**

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $account = $user->account;
 $loans = $user->loans;
 $transactions = $user->transactions;

 return view('User.dashboard', compact('user', 'account', 'loans', 'transactions'));
```

**My view code:**

```
  @isset($loans)
    @foreach ($loans as $loan)
        <div class="widget__status-title text-grey">Transactions</div>
        <div class="widget__spacer"></div>
        <div class="widget__trade"><span class="widget__trade-count">{{ $loan->amount }}</span>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endisset
```

Please I need it to display pending loans, successful transactions in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Make sure relationship is added in the User model.

User.php - Model :

```
    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(YourModelClass::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(YourModelClass::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```